# Error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, mariadb

I want to migrate my database using laravel.
I try this command: `php artisan migrate:fresh --seed` and take this error:

```
Migrating: 2019_10_28_130723_alter_users_table

   Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB ser
ver version for the right syntax to use near 'CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL COLLATE `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`' at line 1 (SQL: ALTER TABLE users CHANGE deductible_amount deductible_a
mount BIGINT UNSIGNED CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL COLLATE `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`)

  at C:\xampp\htdocs\project\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:664
    660|         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    661|         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    662|         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    663|         catch (Exception $e) {
  > 664|             throw new QueryException(
    665|                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    666|             );
    667|         }
    668|

  Exception trace:

  1   Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException::("SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB s
erver version for the right syntax to use near 'CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL COLLATE `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`' at line 1")
      C:\xampp\htdocs\project\vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOConnection.php:63

  2   PDOException::("SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the
 right syntax to use near 'CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL COLLATE `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`' at line 1")
      C:\xampp\htdocs\project\vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOConnection.php:61

  Please use the argument -v to see more details.
```

Here is the content of my `2019_10_28_130723_alter_users_table` migration file:

```php
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class AlterUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->renameColumn('active', 'is_active');
            $table->dropColumn([
                                    'settings',
                                    'google_id',
                                    'github_id',
                                    'telegram_notif',
                                    'income',
                                    'email_notif',
                                    'sms_notif',
                                    'temppass',
                                    'storm_id',
                               ]);
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('deductible_amount')->change();
            $table->softDeletes();
        });
    }



    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->renameColumn('is_active', 'active');
            $table->text('settings');
            $table->string('google_id')->nullable();
            $table->string('github_id')->nullable();
            $table->boolean('telegram_notif')->default(true);
            $table->string('income')->nullable();
            $table->boolean('email_notif')->default(true);
            $table->boolean('sms_notif')->default(false);
            $table->string('temppass')->nullable();
            $table->string('storm_id')->default(null)->nullable();
            $table->string('deductible_amount')->after('wallet')->default('0')->change();
            $table->dropSoftDeletes();
        });
    }
}
```

I don't know how to resolve this problem. I have searched for it, but most of the answers are mentioning a `json` field which must be converted to `string`, which there is no `json` field on my `users` table.
Where is the problem and how can I solve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line causes an error to your migration.

```
$table->unsignedBigInteger('deductible_amount')->change();
```

try to change it to

```
$table->string('deductible_amount')->unsigned()->change();
```

Updated Answer for your situation.

```
        Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('deductible_amount_new');
        });

        DB::statement('UPDATE `users` SET deductible_amount_new=deductible_amount ');

        Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->renameColumn('active', 'is_active');
            $table->dropColumn([
                                    'settings',
                                    'google_id',
                                    'github_id',
                                    'telegram_notif',
                                    'income',
                                    'email_notif',
                                    'sms_notif',
                                    'temppass',
                                    'storm_id',
                               ]);
            $table->dropColumn('deductible_amount');
            $table->softDeletes();
        });

        Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->renameColumn('deductible_amount_new', 'deductible_amount');
        });
```

I hope It can help.

Comment: That line is on the ˋdown` method and will be triggered on the rollback command. I know the problem is on ˋdeductible_amount` field but on the `up` method, cause I am trying the `php artisan migrate` commanr.

Comment: What are you talking about? 
That line is on `up` method in your codes, try to change the type to `string` and the problem will be solved. Thank me later.

Comment: Sorry, it was the copied comment from the other wrong answer which has been deleted now by that user. But I need this field to be integer, cause it is storing integers, not strings.

Comment: This answer didn't even explain.